# Can't start MySQL on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, centos7

The system had MariaDB before which I couldn't start either. Now I deleted MariaDB and installed MySQL.

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

now I try to start daemon mysql with `sudo /sbin/service mysqld start` and at last see

> Job for mysqld.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and journalctl -xn' for details

```
$ systemctl status mysqld.service
mysqld.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) since Пн 2015-02-23 10:49:14 MSK; 16s ago
  Process: 11775 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11764 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11775 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS);         : 11776 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           └─control
             ├─11776 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─12009 sleep 1
```

then try

```
$ journalctl -xn
```

displays "No journal files were found".

file `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Also I saw no form (like on ubuntu) to setup root or password during installation. Have no idea what to do.

Comment: If your journal is broken, you have more serious problems than just MySQL not starting. Fix those, or just reinstall CentOS. - Also, CentOS does not do lots of nonstandard things like Debian/Ubuntu do, so you would need to use the standard `mysql_secure_installation` command to set your MySQL root password (after your issues are fixed).

Comment: I reinstalled MySQL and it works now. May be the problem was in wrong customization during the installation. Thanks to everyone for non-ignoring my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before you use mysql, you have to run through and initialize things using the command:

```
 /usr/bin/mysql_install_db
```

Comment: done that. when tried to start mysql it writes `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock. (2)` I can't find that file in that directory.

Comment: he was created then the service start correctly. Can you put your my.cnf configuration please.

Comment: put this in question